# EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read while trying to compile using PKG

Tags: node.js, sqlite

Im using PKG to compile my code, but I keep getting an error on a sqlite3 module once I try to run my .exe.

```
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1614
      throw error;
      ^
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at error_EISDIR (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:553:17)
    at readFileFromSnapshot (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:894:33)
    at Object.readFileSync (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:938:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1095:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1593:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\Neklita\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js:4:15) {
  errno: -4068,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  path: 'C:\\snapshot\\Neklita\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\\\\\',
  pkg: true
}
```

I can clearly see that the problem is it is getting a directory and not a file.
Went to the file itself (node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js:4:15) and this is the code there.

```
var binary = require('node-pre-gyp');
var path = require('path');
var binding_path = binary.find(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname,'../package.json')));
var binding = require(binding_path);
module.exports = exports = binding;
```

The problem is on binding_path, searching saw I should add that package.json to my pkg assets on main package.json.

```
 "pkg": {
    "scripts": [
      "commands/*.js",
      "events/*.js",
      "node_modules/es-get-iterator/*.js"
    ],
    "assets": [ 
      "media/**/*",
      "node_modules/sqlite3/package.json"
    ]
  },
```

But I keep getting same error, I dont find the solution neither I know how to solve it even knowing were is the error. Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Is it happening after using the specific npm library/package?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. The problem is not the package.json, but the binding_path, which is used in line 4:

```
var binding = require(binding_path)
```

In my case binding_path is "node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-win32-x64/node_sqlite3.node", and

```
    "assets": ["node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-win32-x64/node_sqlite3.node"]
```

solved the problem.